# Why won't my TextBox databinding work?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to get a TextBox control to two-way bind to a string property in a INotifyPropertyChanged object (Person). The Getter is called when the form loads, but the value isn't entered into the TextBox. Likewise, any change in the TextBox does not call the Setter on the Person object.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <TextBox x:Name="txtPersonName" 
DataContext="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Window>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name= "default value";

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Codebehind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Person viewModel = new Person();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the text entered in the textbox get propagated back to the Person object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `XAML` you need to set the TextBox's `Text` property rather than its `DataContext` property